# Maximum set cover of graph

Tags: graph, set-cover

I have a universal set and number of sets S. i need to find maximum number of sets from S such that there is no common element between any choosen two sets.

My Approch--- I have consider each sets in S as a node and if there is any common element between two sets than there would be an edge between these two sets.this approach works fine if the constructed graph is bipartite .. i have difficulty to solve if constructed graph is not bipartite.

P.S.-choosen sets not necessarily be to cover all element from the universal set. it should return maximum number of sets that are no adjacent.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that this is the right SE-site for such a question. IMHO you shoul move this question to either http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have any solution then please suggest it if not then let others  give the answer. question is not purely mathematical it also relates some algorithm part which i needed to solve. answer can also be given here. So please suggest any solution